# How to access 'Program Files' folder in MATLAB

Tags: windows, matlab, executable

Is there any way I can access an executable from within the 'Program Files' folder in MATLAB?

Comment: run matlab with administrator privilege should do it

Comment: @GameOfThrows Administrator privilege is only required if you want to **write** to the Program Files directory.  Accessing is allowed.

Comment: @rayryeng ah I see, I thought execution also required admin privilege.

Comment: @GameOfThrows I just tried it and it works. I wanted to make sure it did before I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical [`cd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) function in MATLAB will help you change directories to facilitate what you need to do.  However, the trick is that the directory has spaces in it, so trying to use `cd` out of the box will give you an error.  You can of course specify a string to decide where you want to change directories, but the direction of the folder separator (i.e. `\` or `/`) is different between operating systems.

I would recommend you use the function [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) so that MATLAB can build a valid directory string by supplying the function with a variable amount of strings where each string is a subdirectory of where you want to navigate to.

In your case, do the following:

```
cd(fullfile('C:', 'Program Files'));
```

Edit the above accordingly if you want to access 32-bit executables where the directory is `Program Files (x86)` as opposed to `Program Files`.

Once you get to this point, you can use the the [`system`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command to execute operating system comments.  You'd use `system` to execute whatever executable you want in this directory. The input takes the path and file of the executable you want to execute.

To see an example, since we're in `Program Files`, I know for sure you'll have Internet Explorer so we can execute the following command in MATLAB, assuming you've already changed your directory to `Program Files`:

```
[status, result] = system(fullfile('Internet Explorer' , 'iexplore.exe &'));
```

It's very important that you have the ampersand `&` sign after the command so that it won't hang MATLAB when you run this command.  It will open up a new Command Prompt window to service the program that you have opened.

`status` gives you a status code where 0 means that the program executed fine while non-zero status codes are followed by an error message. `result` will provide a string that contains whatever was echoed from the command you decided to execute.  For example, if you used `dir`, it will give you a list of files or directories.

You should get Internet Explorer up and running if you followed the above procedure.

---

However, if you don't want to change your directory, you can very simply just provide the full path to the executable in conjunction with `system`:

```
[status, result] = system(fullfile('C:', 'Program Files', 'Internet Explorer', 'iexplore.exe &'));
```